# How do you use the expression “sans crier gare”?

Tags: expressions, usage

I just discovered this phrase and it seems to be like saying “out of the blue” but slightly different? What are some ways to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means "without a warning", or "in an unexpected way".

*Gare* is a rather old interjection for saying "watch out !", so *sans crier gare* means literaly "without shouting *watch out*".

> Il est arrivé sans crier gare, personne ne s'attendait à le voir.

It can be used not only for persons, but also for events (it rather has a connotation of an unpleasant surprise).

> La crise économique a subitement touché notre famille, sans crier gare.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the definition given in the TLFi

> 2. Loc. Sans dire/crier gare. Sans prévenir. Synon. à l'improviste.
>
>    - Il est arrivé sans crier gare.
>    - Milon, sans dire gare, tombe sur lui, le chasse à coups de pied, de poings et le poursuit dehors.
>    - Alors, que faire? La tuer tout simplement et sans crier gare.
>    - Enfin c'était là un nouveau ménage et il allait comme il pouvait, quand l'absente se mit soudain à revenir sans crier gare.

It would seem there is no difference if we read the definition of "out of the blue" in this reference ([reverso](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/out%20of%20the%20blue/forced)).

> out of the blue (adv.); translations: à l'improviste ; sans qu'on s'y attende ; sans prévenir ; inopinément ; de façon inattendue

Nevertheless, I think that "out of the blue" entails a greater estrangement in the situation at hand; it'd be better translated as "tombé du ciel" (Robert Collins).
For instance I would rather say, knowing a person,

- "Il est arrivé chez moi sans crier gare/à l'improviste.",

than

- "Il est arrivé chez moi comme si tombé du ciel.".

However, if I do not know the person the following phrasing would be more appropriate to me;

- Il est arrivé chez moi comme tombé du ciel; je rentrais du travail et il était là, dans le salon où il s'était réfugié.

Another instance  will help in getting a better grasp of this usage;

In this next sentence again, I think that "sans crier gare" is not exact.

- Il a introduit cette équation [sans crier gare/à l'improviste] et a continué à s'en servir jusqu'à ce que quelqu'un lui demande d'où il la sortait.

That's where "out of the blue" (tombé du ciel) confers the idea better in my opinion, although there is a difficulty.

- Cette équation est soudainement apparue sur le tableau sous ses coups de  craie rapides, comme tombée du ciel, et il a continué à s'en servir jusqu'à ce que quelqu'un lui demande d'où il la sortait.